# Combine multiple requestAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript, requestanimationframe

I am playing with JavaScript and I need a little help with requestAnimationFrame.
What I am trying to do is to combine multiple requestAnimationFrame.

For example

Run every 5 seconds the fade function with a duration of 2 seconds.

What I build so far

```
let lastTimeStamp = 0;
let duration = 5000;
let start;
function fadeTimeOut(timeStamp){
  if (!lastTimeStamp || timeStamp - lastTimeStamp >= duration) {
    lastTimeStamp = timeStamp;
    function fade(timeStamp){
      if(!start){ 
              start = timeStamp;
            }
      const opacity = (timeStamp - start) / 2000;
      if(opacity >= 1){
        //Set to zero for blink fx (fadeup only)
        document.getElementById('box').style.opacity = 0;
        return;
      }
      document.getElementById('box').style.opacity = opacity;
      window.requestAnimationFrame(fade);
    }
    window.requestAnimationFrame(fade);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(fadeTimeOut);
}
window.requestAnimationFrame(fadeTimeOut);
```

The code above do run once and is not run every 5 second...

Comment: Why aren't you just using `setInterval`?

Comment: That's not how requestAnimationFrame works. It runs at "your screen's framerate or however much slower your code makes it run" so you use requestAnimationFrame as your outer loop: your master drawing function calls it at the end of itself, so that your master function runs again next frame. And the next frame. And the next frame. Etc. And then in your master function you put all the logic that decides what _actually_ needs to happen based on clock time (e.g `Date.now()` or `performance.now()`). You cannot control how slow, or how fast, requestAnimationFrame runs: it runs on the next free frame

Comment: Any reason to not use simple CSS animations here? If it's actually more complex than what's shown, any reason to not do it with Web Animations instead?

Answer (score 0):

here's a simpler approach to what you need:

```js
let elapsedTime = 0;
let deltaTime = 0.016;

let box = document.querySelector('#box');
let animationTime = 0;

function update(time) {
  // Calculate delta time
  deltaTime = time - elapsedTime;
  deltaTime /= 1000;
  deltaTime = deltaTime < 0.32 ? deltaTime : 0.032;
  elapsedTime = time;
  
  // Animation
  if (animationTime < 5) {
    box.style.opacity = animationTime / 5;
  } else {
    animationTime = 0;
  }
  
  animationTime += deltaTime;
  
  requestAnimationFrame(update);
}

update();
```

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

As you need an external variable anyway, that could simply be a `start` time for the animation, and in the callback you could calculate how much time has elapsed since then, using `Date.now()` (and getting what is called `phase` in the example snippet):

```js
let original=Date.now();
let start=original;
function flashy(){
  let phase=Date.now()-start;
  while(phase>5000){
    phase-=5000;
    start+=5000;
  }
  const level=Math.floor(Math.min(phase/2000*255,255));
  const gray=level.toString(16).padStart(2,"0");
  document.getElementById("btn").style.background="#"+gray+gray+gray;
  document.getElementById("bar").innerText=phase+"".padStart(level/10,"|");
  document.getElementById("check").innerText=start-original;
  requestAnimationFrame(flashy);
}
requestAnimationFrame(flashy);

function pause() {
  const pstart=Date.now();
  while(Date.now()-pstart<500);
}
```

```html
<button id="btn" onclick="pause()">Clicky</button>
<div id="bar"></div>
<div id="check"></div>
```

`original` is just kept to show that the animation occurs at every 5 seconds, no matter what. Pressing the button introduces a half-second busy-wait, which results in skipping that half second of the animation, while the schedule is kept intact.